# JS Toggle: закрытие текущего открытого кода при повторном нажатии другого элемента

Tags: javascript

Имеется код:

```
$('.character__item-container-info-icon').on('click',function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.toggleClass('character__item-container-info_current');
});
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при повторном нажатии, но уже другого элемента, текущий открытый код закрывался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял "текущий открытый код закрывался", но если вы имеете ввиду "как сделать, чтобы при нажатии другого элемента, у родителя текущего убирался класс", то ответ верный:

```
$('.character__item-container-info-icon').on('click',function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent(),
        //запоминаем, есть ли класс в текущего родителя
        parentIsOpen = parent.hasClass('character__item-container-info_current');
    //убираем указанный класс у всех элементов, у которых он есть
    $('.character__item-container-info_current').removeClass('character__item-container-info_current');
    //добавляем класс родителю нашего элемента, если его не было
    if(!parentIsOpen)
        parent.addClass('character__item-container-info_current');
});
```